# fluentlenium-upload file from browser

Tags: file-upload, fluentlenium

I am using fluentlenium for browser testing using java in playframework2.3

I want to upload a file in browser through my test case.
In selenium a function called sendkeys() is used.
What is the similar function in fluentlenium, or is there a any other solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
browser.fill("#file_input_id").with("full path to image file");
browser.click("#submit_button_id");
```

`.with` calls `sendkeys()` internally